# What is the tool GIT uses to draw graph in command-line?

Tags: bash, git, shell, command-line

I want to use that tool to draw undirected graphs with labels on each node.

Does Git use an external tool for that?

Comment: Note that `git` is written in C, not JS. If it does happen to use a 3rd party library, that will also be in C.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It will be a good start for me for finding an equivalent for js or building such thing by myself

Comment: Git doesn't use an external tool. Moreover, Git's graph is specifically a DAG—an undirected and potentially cyclic graph might call for a different layout. Consider using `dot`: see https://www.graphviz.org/

Comment: @StavAlfi I suggest googling "graph visualization library" for your chosen language.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm looking for a bash solution.

Comment: @StavAlfi By "bash solution", do you mean "code written in abash scripting language" or "something I can run from the command line"?

Comment: something I can run in the command-line and print graphs there

Comment: [graph-easy](https://linux.die.net/man/1/graph-easy) might be too limited, but take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you're probably thinking of is `git log --graph`. This functionality [is implemented directly by Git, in C](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/graph.c) -- there are no external tools or libraries involved.

The implementation of these graphs is rather specific to Git histories, and is unlikely to be useful outside this context.